# merge @extend with parent style and make one class name

Tags: css, sass, extend

I'm trying to merge the style into one class but its showing an error. Look at the example below.

```
%banner-style{
  banner {
    padding: 140px 0 210px;
    background: url(https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-92c6382d82ba.jpg) top center/cover no-repeat;
    &.row {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .main-heading {
        font-size: 40px;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding-right: 20px;
        sup {
            font-size: 10px;
            vertical-align: super;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And I want it to merge with the parent class `.parent`

```
.parent{
  color: red;
  &_@extend %banner-style;
}
```

using `&` to merge into one class name. but showing error unless i do this

```
.parent{
      color: red;
      &_{@extend %banner-style};
    }
```

Which is same as if I remove `&_`.

I wanted `.parent_banner {...}` but instead got `.parent_ banner{...}`;

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting exactly what is supposed to happen. Extend does not "merge" classes, it extends another class/placeholder into a new selector's styles.

What that means is if I write:

```
%banner-style {
  background: black;
}

.parent { 
  @extend %banner-style;
}
.other-selector { 
  @extend %banner-style;
  color: red;
}
```

The css I get will be

```
.parent {
  background: black;
}
.other-selector {
  color: red;
  background: black;
}
```

So you are getting expected results. If you'd like to make this "work" the way you want, you can just change your code to:

```
%banner-style {
    padding: 140px 0 210px;
    background: url(https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-92c6382d82ba.jpg) top center/cover no-repeat;
    &.row {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .main-heading {
        font-size: 40px;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding-right: 20px;
        sup {
            font-size: 10px;
            vertical-align: super;
        }
    }
}

.parent{
  color: red;

  &_banner {
    @extend %banner-style;
  };
}
```

Note: I took out the `banner` block because it seems you don't want that (and banner isn't a normal html element).